# What is it called when a single word is offset by commas?

Tags: punctuation, commas

I'm not sure if I can generalize this type of construct, but is there a grammar term for single words surrounded by commas? Consider the following examples:

> 1. Let's assume you are given a length of time, **say**, 10 minutes.
> 2. Tristan was, **unsurprisingly**, late to the meeting.
> 3. The plain-looking building was, **well**, plain.

Are these known as appositives?

Comment: In your examples, it is parenthesis. In other sentences, you might have apposition: *My mother, the Queen of England, likes soap operas.*

Comment: @Cerberus: I agree it would be an apposition in that case, but you could still consider it a parenthesis. I would say that a *partenthesis* is a rethorical/stylistical construct rather then a grammatical one (which an apposition is).

Comment: @nico: Interesting. I have given this some thought, and now I am not sure. Suppose parenthesis were anything set off by soft punctuation marks. Then the relative clause in *the mayor, who was a real jerk, hanged my neighbour* would be parenthetical. Then what about *she was hanged by the mayor, who was a real jerk*? I don't think we want to call this parenthesis, or do we? And *she was hanged by the mayor, a real jerk, on her birthday* is pretty close. What about *I will get her, if she comes, and hang her*? Any other subordinate clause? I'm not sure how to define parenthesis.

Comment: @nico: P.S. I don't think the position of a phrase in the sentence should matter for our calling it parenthesis? Or do you propose so rigid a definition?

Comment: @Cerberus: that's a very good example. I would call `parenthesis` any construct between commas (or dashes, or brackets) that can be removed from the sentence without disrupting it. For instance *the mayor, who was a real jerk, hanged my neighbour* can be rewritten it as *the mayor hanged my neighbour*, preserving the general sense of the sentence, although removing some information. In that sense, when you have it at the end of the sentence the rule still holds: it's between a comma and a full stop, and you can remove it. Same for subordinates.

Comment: @Cerberus: in the example *I will get her, if she comes, and hang her*, you could say *I will get her and hang her*, and still state your intention to hang the person. Of course in this case you lose a very important piece of information, but the sentence is still grammatically intact. As I was saying before, parenthesis is a stylistic construct, used to outline accessory parts of the sentence. Appositions, subordinates, hypothetical statements, are all grammatical constructs, so the two things can coexist.

Comment: Thanks, both of you, but these interesting discussions. I wasn't aware that `parenthesis` meant anything other than the notable punctuation mark.

Comment: @nico: Okay, interesting. So by your definition a parenthetic phrase must fulfil two conditions: it must be set off by the appropriate punctuation marks, and the sentence must still work if you remove it (this isn't purely stylistic). Then what about this: *just give her say fifty dollars and ignore her*? You might say "say" requires commas. But I bet it is often written without: does that deprive it of its parenthetic status? Or does this lie in how it *ought* to be punctuated?

Comment: @nico:  And what about asyndetic main clauses: *he grabbed her, pushed her to the ground, caught the bullet in his shoulder*? Are those last two parenthetic? And what about this: *he loved her, she loved him*? The same as my "say" example: wrong punctuation? *She hated him, and he hated her*: is the second clause parenthetic?

Comment: @Cerberus: in the "say" example you definitely need commas around *say*. If you think of how you pronounce it, it is clear that you pause before and after. The other cases are a bit more complex. Asyndeton is a stylistic scheme, often used to list a series of events (think of the famous *veni, vidi, vici*). In that case I would probably not call them *parenthesys* because you can rewrite the sentence as *veni et vidi et vici*, that is, substituting the comma with a conjunction. I have no reference for that, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The NOAD reports that one of the meaning of *parenthesis* is "a word or phrase inserted as an explanation or afterthought into a passage which is grammatically complete without it, in writing usually marked off by brackets, dashes, or commas."

The same dictionary reports that the meaning of *apposition* (to which I am redirected when I look for the grammatical meaning of *appositive*) is "a relationship between two or more words or phrases in which the two units are grammatically parallel and have the same referent (e.g. *my friend Sue*; *the first US president, George Washington*)."

It seems the right term is *parenthesis*.

Comment: Are parentheses—the punctuation marks ( and )—considered brackets? If so, is it just coincidence that they share the same word as this term, i.e., a parenthesis marked off by parentheses?

Comment: Would it be inappropriate at all to use this construct in more formal writing?

Comment: In American English, _bracket_ means each of the following marks: _[_, _]_; in British English it means each of the following marks: _(_, _)_, _[_, _]_, _{_, _}_, _〈 〉_. The definition of _parenthesis_ I gave is the same for both American and British English. The definition I reported is grammatical; you can surely use _parenthesis_ in formal writing.

Answer (score 3):

It's called a *parenthesis*.

See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parenthesis_%28rhetoric%29) about it.